# How to screen capture AVCameraCapturePreviewLayer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, screenshot

Screen capturing `AVCameraCapturePreviewLayer` looking too dark in screen captured video. Is there any was to screen capture it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to get a frame of the video like the user1111's answer?

Comment: No one will be able to answer this unless you make your question more clear.

Comment: Question looking much understandable! ok for your better understanding, #1 i'm screen capturing a view with its subviews. #2. i'm adding `AVCameraCapturePreviewLayer` which displays camera preview,  to the view. #3. this preview layer not visible in screen captured video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research i found a way to capture camera preview. Just convert `CMSampleBuffer` to   `CIImage` or `UIImage`. [myAvController](https://github.com/benlodotcom/MyAVControllerDemo) sample code gives a prety good solution.

Comment: not bad ! But experiencing memory issue in iphone4!

Comment: Use captureStillImage, this way not give good quality!